# Flogin registration redirect problem

Tags: facebook

Hi 
  I have Facebook register in my website. I have integrated it completely without any bugs and the values are stored in the database.After the successful registration , it doesn't redirect to the exact url that i have mentioned below.

```
  header("location:http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth/?scope=publish_stream&client_id=yyyyy&redirect_uri=".SITE."business.php?action=favouriteshare&id=".$bid."");
```

It always through invalid url details.Could anyone please suggest some ideas to get this redirect correctly.

Comment: Are you sure that the *constant* `SITE` is defined properly? also the value of `$bid`?

Comment: ya i have even reset the code as follows                                                             $urlRed="http://site.com/business.php?action=likeshare&id=".$bid."";   
header("location:http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth/?scope=publish_stream&client_id=84535860448&redirect_uri=".$urlRed."");

Comment: when i am printing the values, i was able to see the $bid, Site everything, but at the time of redirect only it shows problem.

Comment: Okay, try the following: 1) wrap the redirect url with quotes `'` 2) use the `urlencode()` method.

Comment: Okay let me check it out

Comment: BTW, the `scope` parameter is not yet supported. Please vote for this [ticket](http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=14733) to make it happen

Comment: yeah you are correct and millions of thanks for your information.

Comment: Can you please tell me some more ideas in automatic sharing of my website reviews in user FB walll by using their FBid that i have stored during the FB registration.That is whenever they submit some reviews that needs to be shared in there own Fb wall.

Comment: @Anandhan: First of all, did my suggestions solved your primary question? if so, let me add them as an answer.

Comment: @Anandhan: For your second request, you need to gran the `publish_stream` permission to be able to post anything on the user's wall (on his behalf). WHEN to ask for the permission is really up to you and your website logic. I prefer asking a new question for this with more details.

Comment: Yes your answer solved the redirect problem absolutely. Thanks for that.

Comment: @ifaour: I have asked it as a new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5789423/facebook-wall-posting-user-user-facebook-id-in-my-database. Please help me out with some guidance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

1. wrap the redirect url with quotes `'`
2. use the `urlencode()` method.

The `scope` parameter is not yet supported. Please vote this [ticket](http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=14733) to make it happen.